# Tumblr OAuth API - How do get user info?

Tags: api, oauth, tumblr

I've managed to post to tumblr via their OAuth API.

Unfortunately I cannot read posts because the endpoint for reading is http://you.tumblr.com/api/read (with "you" being the user's username), and I cannot find any method for getting the username.

Making a call to http://www.tumblr.com/api/authenticate is supposed to return user info, and the call is successful, but response['body'] is empty.. Any ideas?

Comment: HI there Can you share you code of posting to tumblr via the OAuth? :)

Answer (score 0):

I was successful at getting results from http://www.tumblr.com/api/authenticate
It returns xml (no json option exists) and that xml includes something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tumblr version="1.0">
  <user default-post-format="html" can-upload-audio="1" can-upload-aiff="1" can-ask-question="1" can-upload-video="1" max-video-bytes-uploaded="26214400" liked-post-count="0"/>
  <tumblelog title="Snytkine" is-admin="1" posts="1" twitter-enabled="0" draft-count="0" messages-count="0" queue-count="" name="snytkine" url="http://snytkine.tumblr.com/" type="public" followers="0" avatar-url="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/default_avatar_128.gif" is-primary="yes" backup-post-limit="30000"/>
</tumblr>
```

I have not moved any futher at my Tumblr API script, but from what I see, there is no such thing as tumblr username or userid or user avatar. It's all about blogs. User can have more than one blog and each blog can have own avatar. So maybe substritue "name" for a blog name?

Comment: Bu the way, the correct url is not /api/authenticate but this one: http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize

Comment: Hmm, okay, it may be that the PHP oauth library I'm using is just not returning that data for some reason or is parsing it out. Are you using an oauth library?

Comment: I'm using pecl oauth extension. What library are you using? Generally the library written for Twitter API will not work for Tumblr without some modifications.

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide me with a link to your code?

Comment: Keep an eye on my project at github. I'm going to add "Tumblr" module soon (in a few days), the code to connect Tumblr will be in Controllers dir. https://github.com/snytkine/LampCMS